# How do I assign random values to objects?

Tags: java, random

I am creating a card game that requires the cards to have random attributes. So I created a card class:

```
public static class hero{
static String name;
static int strength;
static int intellect;
static int flight;
static int tech;
}
```

The user then enters the number of cards and an array of cards (objects) is created.

```
hero [] cards = new hero[cardNumber];
           for(int i=0;i<cardNumber;i++){ cards[i]=new hero();}
```

However, when I try to assign random values to the cards using a for loop every card's attribute end up having the same value, this is the code I used:

```
for(int i=0; i<cards.length; ++i)
           {
           cards[i].strength = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
           cards[i].intellect = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
           cards[i].flight = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
           cards[i].tech = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
           }
```

Eg.

```
cards[1].flight
```

would return 7

```
cards[2].flight
```

would return 7

I am pretty sure I am wrong and any help and guidance is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `static` keyword when you declare you variables in your hero class.
So instead of

```
static String name;
...
static int flight;
```

do

```
String name;
...
int flight;
```

Making them `static` makes it so the variable is not specific to a single instance of the class, but rather the class as a whole. Static variables can be called upon without instantiating an object of the class.

For example, with your current code

```
hero.flight
```

would also return 7. By removing the `static` identifier you will be able to make each of the variables specific to each object in your array.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has helped me a lot, initially, I got a null pointer exception error, then I realized that my loop parameters were not the same eg for the first loop  `for(int i=4;i<cardNumber;i++)` and for the second loop `for(int i=4;i<cardNumber;i++)`